# day is out of range for month using strptime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have long list of date in dataframe that need to be converted into datetime, the date is in the form **"%d%m%Y"**, and I apply `datetime.strptime(x,'%d%m%Y')`, which works fine until meet the date **"3122012"**, which should be **datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 3, 0, 0)**, but instead it throw the error message:

```
day is out of range for month
```

which is obviously because the program consider it as 31/2/2012, which doesn't exist. any suggestions to avoid such problems?Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'03122012'`, then?

Comment: Supposedly '3122012' is what I have, any suggestions? sometimes you have  data that are not in the ideal format...

Comment: Have you tried writing your own parser, rather than relying on `datetime.strptime` (which requires well-formed input)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe FYI, `dateutil` throws "year is out of range" error on this input.

Comment: `%d%m%Y` is an ambiguous format. For example, does `1112012` mean `1-11-2012` or `11-1-2012`? So… why are you putting the dates in that format and then trying to parse them back? At any rate, if you really do want to do this and come up with a disambiguation rule (and just accept that some valid dates can never be represented!), however you solve the `1112012` problem, that will give you a solution to the `3122012` problem for free.

Comment: sometimes I am not in charge of data and this is what I get and I have to use it, any suggestions?

Comment: @user6396: Well, either you have to tell whoever is in charge of this data to give you valid data, or you have to document that many perfectly good dates cannot be handled by your system because of some other bonehead who you have no control over and then decide which set of dates you want to make inaccessible. The solution that allows `01-11-2012` but not `11-01-2012` is slightly _simpler_, but that doesn't mean it's necessarily the one you want. Is January or November more important to you?

Comment: That would be the best solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is just part of a much larger problem: Your format is inherently ambiguous.<sup>*</sup>

For example, both `1-11-2012` and `11-1-2012` will format as `1112012`. So, how are you going to parse that? You can invent and implement a disambiguation rule for that, but whichever one you choose, the other date can no longer be represented by your system.

If that's OK with you, then whatever rule you implement for disambiguating `1112012` will automatically handle `3122012` as well. For example:

```
def parse_dmy(s):
    if len(s) == 6: s = '0' + s[0] + '0' + s[1:]
    elif len(s) == 7: s = '0' + s # or s[0] + '0' + s[1:]
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%d%m%Y')
```

I picked the `'0' + s` rule rather than the `s[0] + '0' + s[1:]` rule because the former gives you `03-12-2012` for this example, while the latter gives you `31-02-2012`. But, again, neither rule works for all values.

---

<sub>* Also, `%d` and `%m` explicitly mean "0-padded", so your strings are technically invalid… but most platforms are happy with non-padded numbers in, e.g., `%d-%m-%Y`—I believe POSIX requires them to be happy, and Windows is happy, and what other non-POSIX platform do you care about? Anyway, that would just be a minor problem if not for the larger problem that there is no way to unambiguously convert your strings into a valid format.</sub>